# Why does my code say TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float' I only get the error for numbers over 100,000

Tags: python, if-statement, tuples, typeerror

```
main2 = True
while main2:
    try:
        amount = float(input('annual gross income: '))
        namount = float(amount)
        expenses = float(input('annual expenses: '))
        nnexpenses = float(expenses)



        if(9226 <= namount <= 37450):
                    print('Your tax rate is  $922.50 + 15%')
                    tax = namount - namount*0.15 - 922.50
        if(namount <= 9225):
                    print('Your tax rate is 10%')
                    taxt = namount - namount*0.10
        if(37451 <= namount <= 90750 ):
                    print('Your tax rate is  $5,156.25 + 25%')
                    tax = amount - namount*0.25 - 5,156.25
        if(90751 <= namount <= 189300):
                    print('Your tax rate is  $18,481.25 + 28%')
                    tax = amount - namount*0.28 - 18,481.25 
        if(189301 <= namount <= 411500):
                    print('Your tax rate is  $46,075.25 + 33%')
                    tax = namount - namount*0.33 - 46,075.25
        if(411501 <= namount <= 413200):
                    print('Your tax rate is  $119,401.25 + 35%')
                    tax = namount - namount*0.35 - 119,401.25
        if(413201 <= namount):
                     print('Your tax rate is  $119,996.25 + 39.6%')
                     tax =  namount - namount*0.396 - 119,996.25

        result = float(tax - expenses)
        print('Annual Net Income: ', round(result,2))

    except(ValueError,NameError):
         #if(ValueError):
         print('Please enter a number and postive balance.')
         #else:
             #print('Get out of debt')  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\C2C\Desktop\simplebudget.py", line 33, in <module>
    result = float(tax - expenses)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'
```

Comment: You can't include commas in numbers.

Comment: I took away the comma and I still get the error for numbers over 100,000

Comment: Your tax is tuple type and expenses is float  type. Fix it

Comment: how would I can the tuple to a float without having multiple float arguments

Comment: By. . . removing the commas.

Comment: Just remove the commas, remove it. see the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write a number like this in Python:

```
119,996.25
```

Write it like this:

```
119996.25
```

And so on for all your other numbers that have commas in them.

Answer (score 1):

Your comma within the value causes the problem. That makes the type of your `tax` variable as `tuple`,

```
print type(tax)
print type(expenses)

<type 'tuple'>
<type 'float'>
```

and you are getting:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'
```

Remove them, this is now running successfully in my machine. Though your calculation may be wrong.